# Definir retorno de resultado de função ou método

Tags: python, variáveis, lógica, método

**Edição:** Uma função anterior gera uma lista assim:

```
['Responsável atual', 'Número do processo', 'Foro de tramitação', 'Data da intimação 05/10/2017', 'Data da ação 15/08/2011']
```

Essa é a lista prévia constante em "Dados". Dados é meu relatório final. Ele contém centenas de processos listados. Eu pego um a um desses processos, acesso e ADICIONO as informações de "Partes". Ou seja, eu INCREMENTO essa lista com informações complementares, que são, por exemplo:

```
['Exequente', 'União', '(CNPJ do exequente)', 'Executado', '(CNPJ fictício) 00.345.123/0001-00', 'Nome da empresa executada']
```

A minha função PERCORRE essa lista, ENCONTRA o CNPJ (ou o CPF) alvo e TRATA essa informação para determinar quem será o NOVO responsável. Por isso tem vários elif, pois ele considera o número 3 (imediatamente antes da barra). Se ali tiver 0, 9 ou 8 ele IGNORA e pega o anterior (no caso, o 2). Se ali tiver 0, 9 ou 8 ignora e pega o anterior e assim por diante, por isso é meio confuso o critério de determinação do responsável. No final, quando eu tenho determinado quem é o responsável de acordo com esse critério, eu preciso acrescentar todas essas novas informações dessa lista naquela lista prévia (ou seja, acrescento "Partes" + 'distribuicaoPara' a "Dados") para concluir o relatório...

**#############################**

Tenho uma função:

```
def PegaDadosPartes(dados):
      distribuicaoPara = VerificaDist(partes)
      dados.append(str(distribuicaoPara) + " @")
      for x in range(len(partes)):
          dados.append(partes[x] + '@')
      del partes[0:len(partes)]
      return dados
```

Ela recebe um conjunto de dados (lista 'partes') de outra função, e alimenta uma outra lista ('dados') com essas informações, SENDO QUE a variável 'distribuicaoPara' chama a função 'VerificaDist(partes)' para obter seu valor.

Esse valor depende de uma série de tratamentos. Dentre eles, verificar se em 'partes' há CNPJ's ou CPF's, e tratar diferenciadamente caso a caso, assim:

```
def VerificaDist(partes):
      posicao = []
      temCnpj = 0
      for x in range(len(partes)):
            verificaOutroCnpj = re.search("\d{2}.\d{3}.\d{3}/\d{4}-\d{2}", partes[x]) 
            if verificaOutroCnpj:
                  posicao.append("CNPJ " + verificaOutroCnpj.group())
                  temCnpj = temCnpj + 1
            verificaCpf = re.search("\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}-\d{2}", partes[x]) #Se não achou CNPJ, busca CPF.
            if verificaCpf:
                  posicao.append("CPF " + verificaCpf.group())
      if temCnpj > 0:
            Caso1(posicao) #Primeiro caso: consta CNPJ.
      else:
            Caso2(posicao) #Segundo caso: consta CPF.
```

Tanto em um quanto no outro caso, as funções de tratamento irão "fatiar" a variável, pois os critérios de tratamento são diferentes. No CNPJ o dígito antes da "/" determina o responsável. No CPF, o oitavo dígito define isso. A função final faz isso:

```
def TrataDistribuicao(alvos): #("Alvos" são as partes "fatiadas" da informação)
      analisa = open('C:\\Regras.txt', 'r') #É o arquivo que contém as regras de designação de responsável, tipo "Se o dígito é 8 responsável fulano, se 7 cicrano" e assim por diante...
      regrasDeDistribuicao = analisa.readlines()
      for x in range(len(regrasDeDistribuicao)):
            regrasDeDistribuicao[x] = regrasDeDistribuicao[x].split(',')
      for x in range(len(regrasDeDistribuicao)):
            if alvos[0] == regrasDeDistribuicao[x][0]:
                  distribuicaoPara = str("Distribuir para " + regrasDeDistribuicao[x][1] )
            elif alvos[1] == regrasDeDistribuicao[x][0]:
                  distribuicaoPara = str("Distribuir para " + regrasDeDistribuicao[x][1])
            elif alvos[2] == regrasDeDistribuicao[x][0]:
                  distribuicaoPara = str("Distribuir para " + regrasDeDistribuicao[x][1] )
            elif alvos[3] == regrasDeDistribuicao[x][0]:
                  distribuicaoPara = str("Distribuir para " + regrasDeDistribuicao[x][1])
analisa.close()
```

Ocorre que, no final de tudo isso, não estou conseguindo "setar" a variável "distribuiçãoPara". Como fazer?

Comment: Sinceramente, eu reli sua pergunta umas 5x e ainda não consegui entender. Você tem uma função, `PegaDadosPartes`, que recebe apenas um parâmetro, `dados`, e essa função depende do retorno de outra função, `VerificaDist`, que recebe como parâmetro `partes`, que nem pertence ao escopo; o retorno desta função é adicionado a `dados`, mas depois você itera sobre `partes`, que, de novo, não pertence ao escopo, adicionando seus elementos em `dados`, para no final retornar `dados`. Não fez sentido. Poderia explicar exatamente o que está tentando fazer, pois acho que esta sua solução não é viável.

Comment: E por quê na função `TrataDistribuicao` há 4 `if/elif` que fazem exatamente a mesma coisa?

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta tentando ser mais claro. Obrigado pela atenção!!!

Answer (score 0):

Eu adicionei um `return distribuicaoPara` em cada função posterior, prevendo todas as possibilidades de definição da variável, e o valor finalmente foi retornado! Grato a todos.

Alterei também o laço. Ficou assim:

```
def TrataDistribuicao(alvos):
analisa = open('C:\\Regras.txt', 'r')
regrasDeDistribuicao = analisa.readlines()
for x in range(len(regrasDeDistribuicao)):
    regrasDeDistribuicao[x] = regrasDeDistribuicao[x].split(',')

resultado = None #Acrescentei essa variável para servir de critério pra saída do laço.
for x in range(len(alvos)):
    for y in range(len(regrasDeDistribuicao)):
        if alvos[x] == regrasDeDistribuicao[y][0] and resultado == None:
            resultado = ("Distribuir para " + regrasDeDistribuicao[y][1] + " considerado " + dados[0])

if resultado == None:
    distribuicaoPara = "CNPJ ou CPF não coincidente com nenhuma situação previamente prevista. Verificação manual."
    return distribuicaoPara
else:
    distribuicaoPara = resultado
    return distribuicaoPara
analisa.close()
```